# Why is the src attribute not showing up when I open up the inspector tool?

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying to load a local image by first importing the image and saving it as a variable. Once I have that, I'm passing that to the `src` attribute in my image tag.

I have installed file-loader but the image still isn't loading in my web view. When I opened up inspector in Chrome, strangely, the image tag was missing its `src` attribute.

Here is what I see in the inspector dev tools:
[image]

And here is how I'm creating and passing the image src:

- In my src/app/pages/homepage.js:

  ```
  import image from '../../components/image/prizes.png';
  ...
  <Image imgSrc={image} altText="Prizes" />
  ```
- My Image component, in src/app/components/image/image.js:

  ```
  import React from 'react'
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
  import './image.scss'

  const defaultProps = {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
  }
  const propTypes = {
      imgSource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      altText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      width: PropTypes.string || PropTypes.number,
      height: PropTypes.string || PropTypes.number,
  }
  const Image = props =>
      (
          <div className="image">
              <img src={props.imgSource} alt={props.altText} width={`${props.width}`} height={`${props.height}`} />
          </div>
      )
  Image.defaultProps = defaultProps
  Image.propTypes = propTypes
  export default Image
  ```

Any ideas as to why the `src` attribute is missing when I open up inspector? I'm assuming this is why my image is not displayed/loading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just a simple mis-spelling
you have this in the image component

```
 <img src={props.imgSource}
```

But are passing this

```
<Image imgSrc={image} altText="Prizes" />
```

imgSrc need to be changed imgSource

Comment: Ohmygosh, thank you so much! Can't believe I missed that aha...been staring at the screen too long